# Send emails from WordPress hosted on Microsoft Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, smtp

I'm facing an issue to send mail from our Wordpress website. It is hosted on Azure.

Can anyone tell me what will be an issue there? Is there any service that we need to purchase for SMTP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change port and check.

Answer (score 0):

There are no SMTP service in Azure.  You need to use a 3rd party like SendGrid, Office 365, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at SendGrid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email

Install WordPress plugin: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Alright! so I don't need to do anything on Azure. I have to install the SendGrid plugin in WordPress and setup the things over there.

Comment: If I helped you please mark my reply as answer.

Comment: Hi, there I can see the code there but not a plugin. Can you tell me about plugin installation or custom code? : https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/wordpress-plugin/

Comment: There is a link to plugin download in second paragraph: https://wordpress.org/plugins/sendgrid-email-delivery-simplified/

Comment: Did it help you?